# probability - what probability of randomly choose exactly 5 bad product provided that you put the product to stock

Tags: probability

A company has 100 product with 90 is good products and 10 is bad ones. what probability of getting exactly 5 good
 product out of 20 times you picked from stock given that you return the product to the stock each time you picked one.

Comment: This needs some editing.  You didn't say how many you are drawing.  Is it exactly $5$?  More?  In any case, this is a straight binomial process, with "success" probability $\frac 1{10}$.  The probability of drawing $n$ bad ones in a row is $\left( \frac 1{10} \right)^n$.

Comment: I am sorry, I makes a mistake here,you have to pick 20 times with exactly 5 out of 20 is good ones.this originally modified from the problem where you pick 20 products and get exactly 5 good ones,but you can see the probability of that event is 0 so we modified the problem a little bit

Comment: Ok, well it is still a straight forward [binomial process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) and the usual formulas work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing 20 times. Exactly 5 of those draws must be "bad".
First we must choose which of these 20 draws turn up to be bad, yielding 20C5.
Next we must multiply our answer with the probability of actually getting 5 "bad" draws, which is (1/10)^5. Finally, the answer must be multiplied with the probability of getting the other 15 draws as "good", which is (9/10)^15.
The final answer would be 20C5 * (1/10)^5 * (9/10)^15.
This is a binomial process as every draw is independent of the other, so you can directly approach it with the binomial formula:
P(x=k) = nCk * p^k * (1-p)^n-k
Where x is the random variable representing the number of favorable outcomes, n is the totals number of trials, and p is the probability of success of every trial(which, in this case, is drawing a bad product).
Hope I made everything clear enough.